# PHP concatenation not working properly

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

So i'm trying to build a pagination for my website without refreshing the page. 
I'm using ajax, php and mysql for that purpose.

At  the moment i'm stuck with php, specifically with foreach and concatenation.

Here's my foreach loop:

```
if (isset($_POST['page'])) {
    $algus = $_POST['page'];
    $loos = '';
    $mitu = 5;
    $msg = [];

    foreach (uritused($conn, $id, $algus, $mitu) as $key => $vals) {
        $loos .= "<tr class='tr-data'>";
        $loos .= '<td>'.$vals['eventi_nimi'].'<br><span class="owner" data-id="'.$vals['owner-id'].'">'.$vals['owner'].'</span></td>';
        $loos .= '<td data-loosiaeg="'.$vals['loosiAeg'].'">'.$vals['loosiAeg'].'</td>';
        $loos .= '<td>'.$vals['attendiloos'].'</td>';
        $loos .= '<td>';
        if (is_array($vals['auhinnad'])) {
            foreach($vals['auhinnad'] as $keys => $val){
                $loos .= $val['auhind'].'<br>';
            }
        } else {
            $loos .= $vals['auhinnad'];
        }
        $loos .= '</td>';
        $loos .= '<td>Postitus: '.$vals['tingimused']['postitus'].'<br>Osalus: '.$vals['tingimused']['osalus'].'</td>';
        $loos .= '<td>';
        if (is_array($vals['valista'])) {
            foreach($vals['valista'] as $keys => $val){
                $loos .= $val['nimi'].'<br>';
            }
        } else {
            $loos .= $vals['valista'];
        }
        $loos .= '</td>';
        $loos .= '<td data-sec='.$vals['sec'].' class="tr-icons">
    <i class="material-icons staatus ' . $vals['staatus'] . '" data-staatus="'.$vals['staatus'].'" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-class="stopped" data-eltext="radio_button_checked" data-text="radio_button_unchecked" title="Peata loosimine">radio_button_checked</i></td>';
        $loos .= "</tr>";
    }
    $msg['data'] = $loos;
    $msg['success'] = true;

    echo json_encode($msg);
}
```

Here's my ajax call

```
var page = 1;
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "pages/php/loosid_data.php",
   cache: false,
   dataType: 'json',
   data: {'page': page},
   success: function(msg){
   console.log(msg);
     if(msg['success']){
       $('.tr-data').remove();
       $('.m-loosid table').append(msg['data']);
     }
   },
   error: function(msg){
   console.log(msg);
 }
 });
```

EDIT: Heres the function

```
function uritused($conn, $id, $algus, $mitu){
try{
  $uritused = $conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM loosid WHERE usr_id='$id'");
  $uritused->execute();
}catch(PDOException $e){
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
$uritus_arr = [];
$count = $uritused->fetchColumn();
if($count > 0){
  try{
    $urituseds = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM loosid WHERE usr_id='176237127636' ORDER BY loosiAeg DESC LIMIT 1, 5");
    $urituseds->execute();
  }catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
  }
  $uritus = $urituseds->fetchAll();
    for ($z=0;$z<$count;$z++) {
      $uritus_arr[$z] = array(
        'eventi_nimi' => $uritus[$z]['eventi_nimi'],
        'loosiAeg' => $uritus[$z]['loosiAeg'],
        'tingimused' => array(
          'postitus' => $uritus[$z]['post'],
          'osalus' => $uritus[$z]['osalus']
        ),
        'sec' => $uritus[$z]['sec'],
        'staatus' => $uritus[$z]['staatus'],
        'attendiloos' => $uritus[$z]['attendiloos']
      );
      $auhinnad = explode(',', $uritus[$z]['auhinnad']);
      if($uritus[$z]['auhinnad'] != '-'){
        foreach ($auhinnad as $key) {
            $auhind = explode('-', $key);
            $auhinna_arr[] = array(
              'auhind' => $auhind[0],
              'voitjad' => $auhind[1]
            );
        }
        $uritus_arr[$z]['auhinnad'] = $auhinna_arr;
      }else{
        $uritus_arr[$z]['auhinnad'] = $uritus[$z]['auhinnad'];
      }

      $valista = explode(',', $uritus[$z]['valista']);
      if($uritus[$z]['valista'] != '-'){
        foreach ($valista as $keys) {
            $valistad = explode('-', $keys);
            $valista_arr[] = array(
              'nimi' => $valistad[0],
              'id' => $valistad[1]
            );
        }
        $uritus_arr[$z]['valista'] = $valista_arr;
      }else{
        $uritus_arr[$z]['valista'] = $uritus[$z]['valista'];
      }

      $valista_arr = [];
      $auhinna_arr = [];
    }

}
return $uritus_arr;
}
```

THIS NOW GIVES ME UNDEFINED OFFSET, ALTHOUGH I KNOW THAT THERE'S DATA WITH THAT INFO IN THE DB.
For some reason the data is always empty.
[image]

Whenever i try to run this same code inside my page directly without ajax, everything works as it should.

Maybe you guys have any suggestions on how to fix this? I know that there's already same kind of posts out here but i haven't found my answer yet.

Comment: Show code for the uritused function

Comment: Looks like you have the `dataType: 'json',` but are sending `html` as the response

Comment: Are you sure `uritused` is returning anything?

Comment: @J.D.Pace Yes because like i said when i use the same foreach without ajax directly on my page it works 100%

Comment: @RamRaider No, i'm sending html inside json :D like

{'data': html....}

Comment: @RamRaider I also just tried changng the datatype and php so there wouldn't be no json and it still didn't give me anything. Something seems to be wrong with the foreach but i'm not sure what.

Comment: Edited the question and added uritused function

Comment: I know this probably sound weird as f* but when i use ajax i get nothing from the database, it's like the database is empty but when i echo that foreach directly on my site i get all the data i need. WTF?

Answer (score 0):

@Gino Pane

I'm sorry but thats not the case actually. It seems that i made a rookie mistake with my query. I have only one instance of data in the database but my limit is set to 1, 5 but it should be 0, 5.

Basically my query was looking data from the database starting at 1 when it should've started at 0. Thats why it seemed to me that there is no data in the database.

I also said that when i echo foreach directly on the page it works because i had more than 1 instance of data in the database at that time.

Sorry for wasting your time guys.

Comment: Not a time waster.  Bringing other eyes into the problem is a great way to solve it, even if you're the one who ultimately solves it.  We've all solved our own problems after explaining it to someone else.